# cloud-init services not starting after reboot

Tags: linux, cloud, suse, openstack

cloud-init services not starting after reboot. I am using Suse 15 and my instance is running on openstack cloud.

OS details:

```
NAME="SLES"  
VERSION="15"  
VERSION_ID="15"  
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15"  
ID="sles"  
ID_LIKE="suse"  
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"  
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:15"
```

Cloud-init version:

```
cloud-init 19.1
```

Even we enable all the services but still having same issue.

All soft links created in "/etc/systemd/system/cloud-init.target.wants"

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Jun 24 07:16 cloud-config.service ->
 /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-config.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jun 24 07:16 cloud-final.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-final.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Jun 24 07:21 cloud-init-local.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-init-local.service  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Jun 25 05:04 cloud-init.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-init.service
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser! Could you please edit your question and add the output of `systemctl status cloud-init.service` and `journalctl -eu cloud-init.service`? Could you also add more information on how have you configured these services, how have you enabled them, how have you configured the `.target` which I see you use?

Comment: cloud-init.service - Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud-init.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: journalctl -eu cloud-init.service  -- Logs begin at Tue 2019-06-25 10:57:15 UTC,  
 end at Tue 2019-06-25 10:57:57 UTC. --
-- No entries --

Answer (score 1):

that happens because cloud-init cant [determinate](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/openstack.html) the platform. To fix it, you have to the datasource_list:

```
cat <<EOF >>/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/01_ds-identify.cfg
datasource_list: [ OpenStack, None ]
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only you have to define a datasource_list in your cloud-init config, as shown in [cloud-init services not starting after reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/1452633/cloud-init-services-not-starting-after-reboot/1510908#1510908), but you have to make sure your YAML list is formatted as an one-liner. The cloud-init YAML parser is not capable to read valid multi-line YAML lists.

See also https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/b5aecbe9512fa546255cc93b178b4081342fc247/tools/ds-identify#L547-L566